# Terraform AWS creates two launch templates while creating EKS Cluster & managed node group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

our EKS infrastructure created with Terraform, includes the resource set below. But in this setup, surprisingly, two launch templates are created and when I try to add user_data section to my launch template, this change doesn't take effect on node group because auto scaling group is using the secong launch template that is not being created via Terraform.
My questions are,
what is the purpose of second launch template since I'm creating one and giving it to node group?
How can I avoid AWS to create second launch template?

```
module "eks-cluster" {
  source = "../../aws/eks-cluster-v2"
  
  name                      = var.eks_cluster_name
  role_arn                  = var.eks_cluster_iam_role_arn
  eks_cluster_version       = var.eks_cluster_version
  enabled_cluster_log_types = var.eks_cluster_enabled_log_types
  subnet_ids              = var.eks_cluster_subnet_ids
  endpoint_private_access = var.eks_cluster_endpoint_private_access
  public_access_cidrs     = var.eks_cluster_public_access_ips

  tags = {
      Environment  = var.environment
      Name = var.eks_cluster_name
      Version = var.eks_cluster_version
    }

  depends_on = [module.eks-cluster-cloudwatch-log-group]

}

module "eks-nodegroup-launch-template" {
  source = "../../aws/launch-template"

  name                   = "${var.eks_cluster_name}-${var.eks_nodegroup_name}-launch-template"
  update_default_version = var.launch_template_update_default_version
  instance_type = var.launch_template_instance_type
  key_name = var.launch_template_key_pair_name
  block_device_name = var.launch_template_block_device_name
  volume_size = var.launch_template_disk_size
  ebs_optimized = var.launch_template_ebs_optimized
  monitoring_enabled = var.launch_template_monitoring_enabled
  resources_to_tag = var.launch_template_resource_type

  tags = {
      Environment  = var.environment
      Name  = "${var.eks_cluster_name}-${var.eks_nodegroup_name}-nodes"
    }

}

module "eks-nodegroup" {
  source = "../../aws/eks-nodegroup-v2"

  cluster_name    = module.eks-cluster.eks_cluster_name
  node_group_name = var.eks_nodegroup_name
  node_role_arn  = var.eks_nodegroup_iam_role_arn
  subnet_ids     = var.eks_nodegroup_subnet_ids
  desired_size = var.eks_nodegroup_desired_size
  max_size     = var.eks_nodegroup_max_size
  min_size     = var.eks_nodegroup_min_size
  launch_template_id        = module.eks-nodegroup-launch-template.launch_template_id
  launch_template_version   = var.eks_nodegroup_launch_template_version

  labels = {
    "env" = var.environment
    "nodegroup_name" = var.eks_nodegroup_name
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = var.environment
    cluster_name = var.eks_cluster_name
  }

  depends_on = [module.eks-nodegroup-launch-template, module.eks-cluster]
}
```

Comment: Most probably module "eks-cluster" is creating a node group itself. Then again you are creating another node group.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the purpose of second launch template since I'm creating one
> and giving it to node group?

If you create the node group like that the launch template you are creating will be assigned to the node group. This is the so-called custom launch template in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managed-node-groups.html#managed-node-group-concepts) and it is used for:

> The custom launch template can be used to provide a greater level of
> flexibility and customization when deploying managed nodes. For
> example, you can specify extra kubelet arguments and use a custom AMI.

Now EKS will additionally create an auto scaling group (to implement things like the max, min & desired_size in your code) and for the auto scaling group to know work it needs to know how to configure the new machines (instance type, AMI, etc.) it needs either a launch configuration or a launch template. In this case a launch template. So this is the second launch template that is being created. About this one the AWS documentation says:

> Don't manually modify this auto-generated template or errors occur.

So when creating the node, which configuration is taken from the auto scaling launch template and which from the custom launch template? The complete list can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html#launch-template-basics

There you also have a section about user data.

> How can I avoid AWS to create second launch template?

It does not seem you can avoid the creation of the auto scaling group's launch template and as for the documentation you should not even modify it.

Still in terraform you can find out this launch template by using the [eks_node_group.autoscaling_groups](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group#autoscaling_groups) attribute or the eks_node_group data source. From there you can read the [autoscaling_group.launch_template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group#launch_template) argument and you have a reference to what you want to modify.